# sorting on vb.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

trying to implement a sort on my gridview as below, its not quite working as I'd expect 1. it doesn't sort by the first column as i'd like, first column descending 2. when i click each of the columns they appear to change order but i can't determine what is actually sorting asc/desc. i really only need the first column which is the id to sort desc.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Query
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then            
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub BindGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim strConnString As [String] = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString()
    Dim strQuery As String = "select id,relates_to,'../../' + location as location from Files;"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    Try
        con.Open()
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd
        sda.Fill(dt)
        ViewState("dt") = dt
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        sda.Dispose()
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim item As String = e.Row.Cells(0).Text
        For Each button As Button In e.Row.Cells(3).Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
            If button.CommandName = "Delete" Then
                button.Attributes("onclick") = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + item + "?')){ return false; };"
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ToString())                
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Files WHERE id = @id"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Dim strBetID As String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = strBetID
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        BindGrid()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub LinkButtonUsers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonUsers.Click
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Admin/Users.aspx")
End Sub

Private Sub LinkButtonTips_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonTips.Click
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Admin/Admin.aspx")
End Sub

Private Sub LinkButtonEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonEmail.Click
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Admin/Email.aspx")
End Sub

Private Sub LinkButtonKnowledge_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonKnowledge.Click
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Admin/Knowledge.aspx")
End Sub

Protected Sub LinkButtonQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonQuery.Click
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Admin/Query.aspx")
End Sub

Protected Sub OnPageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs)
    Dim dt As DataTable = ViewState.Item("dt")
    Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
    Dim sd As String = ""

    If Not dt Is Nothing Or Not dt Is "" Then
        If e.SortDirection.ToString.Contains("asc") Then
            sd = "asc"
        ElseIf e.SortDirection.ToString.Contains("desc") Then
            sd = "desc"
        Else
            sd = "asc"
        End If
    End If

    Try
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sd
        dt = dv.ToTable
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try        
End Sub
End Class
```

aspx is as such:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" 
                    OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" EnableModelValidation="True" AllowSorting="true"  
                    OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="relates_to" HeaderText="relates_to" SortExpression="relates_to" />                                                        
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview Image" SortExpression="location">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("location")%>'
                                Width="100px" Height="100px" Style="cursor: pointer" OnClientClick="return LoadDiv(this.src);" />
                        </ItemTemplate>    
                            </asp:TemplateField>                        
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
                    </Columns> 
                </asp:GridView>
```

am tempted to re-write the lot again using another approach as i have kind of cobbled this together from a couple of sources on the net and presumed it would be okay? probably something minor like the viewstate aspect but can't fathom it out at the moment!?..

Comment: You could add an `Order By` statement in your SQL string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of storing the DataTable in the ViewState, you can call `BindGrid` from the Sorting event to populate the GridView. If you include the data sorting in that method, it will apply in all situations.

The sorting parameters can be stored in the ViewState (or in Session):

```
Protected Property SortExpression As String
    Get
        Dim value as Object = ViewState("SortExpression")
        Return If(Not IsNothing(value), CStr(value), "id")
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("SortExpression") = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Property IsAscendingSort As Boolean
    Get
        Dim value as Object = ViewState("IsAscendingSort")
        Return If(Not IsNothing(value), CBool(value), False)
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        ViewState("IsAscendingSort") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

They can be set in the Sorting event handler:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs)
    If e.SortExpression = SortExpression Then
        IsAscendingSort = Not IsAscendingSort
    Else
        SortExpression = e.SortExpression
    End If
    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

And used in the `BindGrid` method:

```
Protected Sub BindGrid()
    ...
    sda.Fill(dt)
    Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
    dv.Sort = SortExpression + " " + If(IsAscendingSort, "ASC", "DESC")
    GridView1.DataSource = dv
    GridView1.DataBind()
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks this is brilliant! :) :) just one other question i presumed placing order by 1 desc in the sql query might have given me a sort on the first column descending when my gridview is loaded but seems to ignore this is there a proper way to get a sort desc on the first column when its first loaded...

Comment: I had specified `True` by default for the `IsAscendingSort` property. I modified the answer to return `False`; that should do what you want.

Comment: By the way, you can choose the initial sort column by setting the default value for `SortExpression`. In my answer, the default is the `id` field.